# Clean create-react-native-app not starting

Tags: react-native, npm

A clean `create-react-native-app AwesomeProject` is not starting. 
Probably something on my environment not properly configured. I messed around with **node** and **npm** but I'm not familiar with them so I might have messed something up. 
 
npm -v 6.0.1 
node --version v9.4.0 
create-react-native-app version: 1.0.0

```
0 info it worked if it ends with ok
1 verbose cli [ '/home/caiof/.nvm/versions/node/v9.4.0/bin/node',
1 verbose cli   '/home/caiof/.nvm/versions/node/v9.4.0/bin/npm',
1 verbose cli   'start' ]
2 info using npm@6.0.1
3 info using node@v9.4.0
4 verbose run-script [ 'prestart', 'start', 'poststart' ]
5 info lifecycle AwesomeProject@0.1.0~prestart: AwesomeProject@0.1.0
6 info lifecycle AwesomeProject@0.1.0~start: AwesomeProject@0.1.0
7 verbose lifecycle AwesomeProject@0.1.0~start: unsafe-perm in lifecycle true
8 verbose lifecycle AwesomeProject@0.1.0~start: PATH: /home/caiof/.nvm/versions/node/v9.4.0/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/npm-lifecycle/node-gyp-bin:/home/caiof/dev/react/react-native/native-apps/AwesomeProject/node_modules/.bin:/home/caiof/.nvm/versions/node/v9.4.0/bin:/home/caiof/dev/bitcoin-core/bitcoin-0.15.1/bin:/home/caiof/dev/android-sdk/platform-tools:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin
9 verbose lifecycle AwesomeProject@0.1.0~start: CWD: /home/caiof/dev/react/react-native/native-apps/AwesomeProject
10 silly lifecycle AwesomeProject@0.1.0~start: Args: [ '-c', 'react-native-scripts start' ]
11 silly lifecycle AwesomeProject@0.1.0~start: Returned: code: 1  signal: null
12 info lifecycle AwesomeProject@0.1.0~start: Failed to exec start script
13 verbose stack Error: AwesomeProject@0.1.0 start: `react-native-scripts start`
13 verbose stack Exit status 1
13 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.<anonymous> (/home/caiof/.nvm/versions/node/v9.4.0/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/npm-lifecycle/index.js:283:16)
13 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.emit (events.js:160:13)
13 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (/home/caiof/.nvm/versions/node/v9.4.0/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/npm-lifecycle/lib/spawn.js:55:14)
13 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:160:13)
13 verbose stack     at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:943:16)
13 verbose stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:220:5)
14 verbose pkgid AwesomeProject@0.1.0
15 verbose cwd /home/caiof/dev/react/react-native/native-apps/AwesomeProject
16 verbose Linux 4.15.0-20-generic
17 verbose argv "/home/caiof/.nvm/versions/node/v9.4.0/bin/node" "/home/caiof/.nvm/versions/node/v9.4.0/bin/npm" "start"
18 verbose node v9.4.0
19 verbose npm  v6.0.1
20 error code ELIFECYCLE
21 error errno 1
22 error AwesomeProject@0.1.0 start: `react-native-scripts start`
22 error Exit status 1
23 error Failed at the AwesomeProject@0.1.0 start script.
23 error This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
24 verbose exit [ 1, true ]
```